# Mis-configured domain, causing 104 (connection reset by peer) error on heroku website

Tags: .htaccess, heroku, dns

I have a misconfigured heroku website. It shows error 104 (Read Error: Connection reset by peer) upon typing its URL and hitting enter. But subsequently refreshing the URL a couple of times makes the URL **load correctly** (some kind of fallback kicks in? - not that I knowingly configured any). The URL is http://damadam.in/ (it's a naked domain).

I bought this domain from godaddy. In Godaddy's control panel where I have the DNS Zone file, the host www points to damadam.herokuapp.com (under CName). http://damadam.in is set to forward to http://www.damadam.in. Lastly, in my heroku control panel **both** http://damadam.in and http://www.damadam.in have damadam.herokuapp.com as the DNS target (could this last configuration be the problem)?

Can someone help me properly set this thing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a http response code, but rather an error number indicating something was wrong with the connection.

"Connection reset by peer" means that, on the route from your computer to the final destination, a node decided to forcefully stop and reset the connection. On a configuration level I don't think you will be able to do much about this. If there was some kind of DNS misconfiguration, you would not see a read error, but a DNS Error instead.

Make sure that your local network is stable (e.g. connect to your modem with an ethernet cable, rather than through wifi). If this connection is stable, try again at a later date. Connections between nodes can break, and in some cases not all traffic might be able to reach the intended destination. If behaviour persists through a greater length of time, contact your host, in this case Godaddy, and ask them to look into this problem. It might be just a faulty piece of equipment

Comment: Could it be that in heroku, both damadam.in and www.damadam.in point to damadam.herokuapp.com, whereas in GoDaddy, damadam.in forwards to www.damadam.in, which in turn points to the heroku app? There's some inconsistency here...

Comment: Your DNS setup looks fine. Probably it is your network access that is unstable (I couldn't get that error even once, while reloading your site)

Comment: @HassanBaig It doesn't sound like an unreasonable configuration to me.

Comment: Okay, thanks I guess. Dropping godaddy a dime. If nothing else happens, will select this answer as the correct one in a couple of days. Though if their support throws me a curveball, allow me to get back to you on this thread :-)